# Getting Error In Swagger(drf_yasg library) For Nested Serializers in Django

Tags: python, django, swagger, django-serializer, drf-yasg

I'm using drf_yasg library in django. Normally everything was working correctly. When I use the nested serializer, I get the following error in the swagger interface.

**Error: **

```
Internal Server Error: /swagger/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\userx1\OneDrive\Desktop\projectx_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\userx1\OneDrive\Desktop\projectx_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\userx1\OneDrive\Desktop\projectx_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\userx1\OneDrive\Desktop\projectx_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\userx1\OneDrive\Desktop\projectx_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\userx1\OneDrive\Desktop\projectx_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\userx1\OneDrive\Desktop\projectx_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\userx1\OneDrive\Desktop\projectx_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\userx1\OneDrive\Desktop\projectx_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\drf_yasg\views.py", line 94, in get
    schema = generator.get_schema(request, self.public)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\userx1\OneDrive\Desktop\projectx_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\drf_yasg\generators.py", line 246, in get_schema
    paths, prefix = self.get_paths(endpoints, components, request, public)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\userx1\OneDrive\Desktop\projectx_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\drf_yasg\generators.py", line 404, in get_paths
    operation = self.get_operation(view, path, prefix, method, components, request)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\userx1\OneDrive\Desktop\projectx_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\drf_yasg\generators.py", line 446, in get_operation
    operation = view_inspector.get_operation(operation_keys)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\userx1\OneDrive\Desktop\projectx_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\drf_yasg\inspectors\view.py", line 32, in get_operation
    body = self.get_request_body_parameters(consumes)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\userx1\OneDrive\Desktop\projectx_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\drf_yasg\inspectors\view.py", line 82, in get_request_body_parameters
    return self.get_request_form_parameters(serializer)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\userx1\OneDrive\Desktop\projectx_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\drf_yasg\inspectors\view.py", line 134, in get_request_form_parameters
    return self.serializer_to_parameters(serializer, in_=openapi.IN_FORM)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\userx1\OneDrive\Desktop\projectx_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\drf_yasg\inspectors\base.py", line 448, in serializer_to_parameters
    return self.probe_inspectors(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\userx1\OneDrive\Desktop\projectx_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\drf_yasg\inspectors\base.py", line 110, in probe_inspectors
    result = method(obj, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\userx1\OneDrive\Desktop\projectx_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\drf_yasg\inspectors\field.py", line 48, in get_request_parameters
    parameters = [
                 ^
  File "C:\Users\userx1\OneDrive\Desktop\projectx_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\drf_yasg\inspectors\field.py", line 49, in <listcomp>
    self.probe_field_inspectors(
  File "C:\Users\userx1\OneDrive\Desktop\projectx_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\drf_yasg\inspectors\base.py", line 228, in probe_field_inspectors
    return self.probe_inspectors(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\userx1\OneDrive\Desktop\projectx_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\drf_yasg\inspectors\base.py", line 110, in probe_inspectors
    result = method(obj, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\userx1\OneDrive\Desktop\projectx_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\drf_yasg\inspectors\field.py", line 77, in field_to_swagger_object
    child_schema = self.probe_field_inspectors(field.child, ChildSwaggerType, use_references)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\userx1\OneDrive\Desktop\projectx_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\drf_yasg\inspectors\base.py", line 228, in probe_field_inspectors
    return self.probe_inspectors(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\userx1\OneDrive\Desktop\projectx_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\drf_yasg\inspectors\base.py", line 110, in probe_inspectors
    result = method(obj, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\userx1\OneDrive\Desktop\projectx_backend\venv\Lib\site-packages\drf_yasg\inspectors\field.py", line 86, in field_to_swagger_object
    raise SwaggerGenerationError("cannot instantiate nested serializer as " + swagger_object_type.__name__)
drf_yasg.errors.SwaggerGenerationError: cannot instantiate nested serializer as Items
[10/Jun/2023 20:11:13] "GET /swagger/?format=openapi HTTP/1.1" 500 278531
```

**My Models:**

```
class Car(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    car_number = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class CarFiles(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    file = models.FileField(default=None, blank=True, null=True, validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['pdf'])])
    car = models.ForeignKey("Car", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='car_files')
```

**My Serializers:**

```
class CarFilesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CarPassanger
        exclude = ['car']

class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    car_files = CarFilesSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = '__all__'
```

When I update the `car_files` field in `CarSerializer` to `car_files = CarFilesSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)`, the swagger interface opens. However, it is not a suitable use for post processing.